# crosstool-ng configuration settings

Tags: linux, cross-compiling, toolchain, crosstool-ng

I want build cross toolchain for ARM target. I downloaded crosstool-ng package, in addition to crosstool-ng source tarball itself, it contains also all the source tarballs that crosstool-ng needs to build the crosstool chain (few Linux versions, glibc, binutils), the configuration file of crosstool-ng to build the cross toolchain, and building script build.sh. It already have basic config for arm-926ejs, but I need adjust it for my needs.
I need build gcc compiler with the following options:

```
    ~$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
    Using built-in specs.
    Target: arm-linux-gnueabi
    Configured with: ../gcc/configure 
--target=arm-linux-gnueabi \
--host=x86_64-gnu-linux \
--build=x86_64-gnu-linux \
--with-sysroot=/opt/emlix/bde55/sysroot \
--enable-__cxa_atexit \
--enable-c99 \
--disable-nls \
--enable-long-long \
--enable-threads=posix \
--prefix=/opt/emlix/bde55 \
--disable-libssp \
--disable-libgomp \
--disable-libmudflap \
--enable-languages=c,c++ \
--disable-libstdcxx-pch \
--enable-cxx-flags=-march=armv5te -Wa,-march=armv5te \
--with-gxx-include-dir=/opt/emlix/bde55/sysroot/usr/include/c++/4.1.2 \
--with-versuffix= (Emlix Linux 4.1.2-1) \
--with-mtune=arm9e \
--with-arch=armv5te \
--enable-tls \
--enable-target-optspace
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.1.2
```

---

I can't add the aboved options into configuration file,  I just don't see the the matching items in the configuration file below, except CPU arch.

config file:

```
#
# Automatically generated make config: don't edit
# crosstool-NG 1.20.0 Configuration
# Wed Oct  1 17:02:21 2014
#
CT_CONFIGURE_has_xz=y
CT_CONFIGURE_has_cvs=y
CT_CONFIGURE_has_svn=y
CT_MODULES=y

#
# Paths and misc options
#

#
# crosstool-NG behavior
#
# CT_OBSOLETE is not set
# CT_EXPERIMENTAL is not set
# CT_DEBUG_CT is not set

#
# Paths
#
CT_LOCAL_TARBALLS_DIR="/local/home/gmouchard/unisim/git/benchmarks/generic/cross_compiler/downloads"
# CT_SAVE_TARBALLS is not set
CT_WORK_DIR="${CT_TOP_DIR}/.build"
CT_PREFIX_DIR="/local/home/gmouchard/unisim/git/benchmarks/generic/cross_compiler/arm-926ejs-linux-gnueabi"
CT_INSTALL_DIR="${CT_PREFIX_DIR}"
CT_RM_RF_PREFIX_DIR=y
CT_REMOVE_DOCS=y
CT_INSTALL_DIR_RO=y
CT_STRIP_ALL_TOOLCHAIN_EXECUTABLES=y

#
# Downloading
#
# CT_FORBID_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_FORCE_DOWNLOAD is not set
CT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=10
# CT_ONLY_DOWNLOAD is not set
# CT_USE_MIRROR is not set

#
# Extracting
#
# CT_FORCE_EXTRACT is not set
CT_OVERIDE_CONFIG_GUESS_SUB=y
# CT_ONLY_EXTRACT is not set
CT_PATCH_BUNDLED=y
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_BUNDLED_FALLBACK_LOCAL is not set
# CT_PATCH_LOCAL_FALLBACK_BUNDLED is not set
# CT_PATCH_NONE is not set
CT_PATCH_ORDER="bundled"

#
# Build behavior
#
CT_PARALLEL_JOBS=8
CT_LOAD=""
CT_USE_PIPES=y
CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=""
CT_EXTRA_CFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
CT_EXTRA_LDFLAGS_FOR_HOST=""
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_SH is not set
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_ASH is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL_BASH=y
# CT_CONFIG_SHELL_CUSTOM is not set
CT_CONFIG_SHELL="${bash}"

#
# Logging
#
# CT_LOG_ERROR is not set
# CT_LOG_WARN is not set
CT_LOG_INFO=y
# CT_LOG_EXTRA is not set
# CT_LOG_ALL is not set
# CT_LOG_DEBUG is not set
CT_LOG_LEVEL_MAX="INFO"
# CT_LOG_SEE_TOOLS_WARN is not set
CT_LOG_PROGRESS_BAR=y
CT_LOG_TO_FILE=y
CT_LOG_FILE_COMPRESS=y

#
# Target options
#
CT_ARCH="arm"
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_BOTH_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_BOTH_ENDIAN=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_32=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_64=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_ARCH=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_CPU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_TUNE=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_FLOAT=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_WITH_FPU=y
CT_ARCH_SUPPORTS_SOFTFP=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_HAS_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_LE=y
CT_ARCH_DEFAULT_32=y
CT_ARCH_ARCH="armv5te"
CT_ARCH_CPU="arm926ej-s"
CT_ARCH_TUNE="arm926ej-s"
CT_ARCH_FPU="vfp"
# CT_ARCH_BE is not set
CT_ARCH_LE=y
CT_ARCH_32=y
# CT_ARCH_64 is not set
CT_ARCH_BITNESS=32
# CT_ARCH_FLOAT_HW is not set
CT_ARCH_FLOAT_SW=y
CT_TARGET_CFLAGS=""
CT_TARGET_LDFLAGS=""
# CT_ARCH_alpha is not set
CT_ARCH_arm=y
# CT_ARCH_avr32 is not set
# CT_ARCH_blackfin is not set
# CT_ARCH_m68k is not set
# CT_ARCH_mips is not set
# CT_ARCH_powerpc is not set
# CT_ARCH_s390 is not set
# CT_ARCH_sh is not set
# CT_ARCH_sparc is not set
# CT_ARCH_x86 is not set
CT_ARCH_alpha_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_arm_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_avr32_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_blackfin_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_m68k_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_microblaze_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_mips_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_powerpc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_s390_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sh_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_sparc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_x86_AVAILABLE=y
CT_ARCH_SUFFIX=""

#
# Generic target options
#
# CT_MULTILIB is not set
CT_ARCH_USE_MMU=y
CT_ARCH_ENDIAN="little"

#
# Target optimisations
#
# CT_ARCH_FLOAT_AUTO is not set
# CT_ARCH_FLOAT_SOFTFP is not set
CT_ARCH_FLOAT="soft"

#
# arm other options
#
CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE="arm"
CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE_ARM=y
# CT_ARCH_ARM_MODE_THUMB is not set
# CT_ARCH_ARM_INTERWORKING is not set
CT_ARCH_ARM_EABI_FORCE=y
CT_ARCH_ARM_EABI=y

#
# Toolchain options
#

#
# General toolchain options
#
CT_FORCE_SYSROOT=y
CT_USE_SYSROOT=y
CT_SYSROOT_NAME="sysroot"
CT_SYSROOT_DIR_PREFIX=""
CT_WANTS_STATIC_LINK=y
# CT_STATIC_TOOLCHAIN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_PKGVERSION=""
CT_TOOLCHAIN_BUGURL=""

#
# Tuple completion and aliasing
#
CT_TARGET_VENDOR="926ejs"
CT_TARGET_ALIAS_SED_EXPR=""
CT_TARGET_ALIAS=""

#
# Toolchain type
#
CT_CROSS=y
# CT_CANADIAN is not set
CT_TOOLCHAIN_TYPE="cross"

#
# Build system
#
CT_BUILD=""
CT_BUILD_PREFIX=""
CT_BUILD_SUFFIX=""

#
# Misc options
#
# CT_TOOLCHAIN_ENABLE_NLS is not set

#
# Operating System
#
CT_KERNEL_SUPPORTS_SHARED_LIBS=y
CT_KERNEL="linux"
CT_KERNEL_VERSION="3.14.11"
# CT_KERNEL_bare_metal is not set
CT_KERNEL_linux=y
CT_KERNEL_bare_metal_AVAILABLE=y
CT_KERNEL_linux_AVAILABLE=y
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_15 is not set
CT_KERNEL_V_3_14=y
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_13 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_12 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_11 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_10 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_9 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_8 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_7 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_6 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_5 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_4 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_3 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_2 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_3_0 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_39 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_38 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_37 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_36 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_33 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_32 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_31 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_V_2_6_27 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_CUSTOM is not set
CT_KERNEL_windows_AVAILABLE=y

#
# Common kernel options
#
CT_SHARED_LIBS=y

#
# linux other options
#
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_0=y
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_1 is not set
# CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSITY_2 is not set
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_VERBOSE_LEVEL=0
CT_KERNEL_LINUX_INSTALL_CHECK=y

#
# Binary utilities
#
CT_ARCH_BINFMT_ELF=y
CT_BINUTILS="binutils"
CT_BINUTILS_binutils=y

#
# GNU binutils
#
CT_BINUTILS_V_2_22=y
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_53 is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_21_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_20_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_19_1a is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_V_2_18a is not set
CT_BINUTILS_VERSION="2.22"
CT_BINUTILS_2_22_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_21_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_20_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_19_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_2_18_or_later=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_HASH_STYLE=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_GOLD=y
CT_BINUTILS_GOLD_SUPPORTS_ARCH=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PLUGINS=y
CT_BINUTILS_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_BINUTILS_FORCE_LD_BFD=y
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD=y
# CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_LD_GOLD is not set
# CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_GOLD_LD is not set
CT_BINUTILS_LINKERS_LIST="ld"
CT_BINUTILS_LINKER_DEFAULT="bfd"
# CT_BINUTILS_PLUGINS is not set
CT_BINUTILS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
# CT_BINUTILS_FOR_TARGET is not set

#
# binutils other options
#

#
# C-library
#
CT_LIBC="glibc"
CT_LIBC_VERSION="2.19"
# CT_LIBC_eglibc is not set
CT_LIBC_glibc=y
# CT_LIBC_musl is not set
# CT_LIBC_uClibc is not set
CT_LIBC_eglibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_THREADS="nptl"
CT_LIBC_glibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_19=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_18 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_17 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_16_0 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_15 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_14_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_14 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_13 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_12_2 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_12_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_11_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_11 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_10_1 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_9 is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_V_2_8 is not set
CT_LIBC_mingw_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_musl_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_newlib_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_none_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_uClibc_AVAILABLE=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_ANY=y
CT_LIBC_SUPPORT_THREADS_NATIVE=y

#
# Common C library options
#
CT_THREADS_NATIVE=y
CT_LIBC_XLDD=y
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_PORTS_EXTERNAL is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MAY_FORCE_PORTS=y
CT_LIBC_glibc_familly=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_CONFIGPARMS=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_EXTRA_CFLAGS=""
CT_LIBC_EXTRA_CC_ARGS="-g"
# CT_LIBC_DISABLE_VERSIONING is not set
CT_LIBC_OLDEST_ABI=""
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_FORCE_UNWIND=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_USE_PORTS=y
CT_LIBC_ADDONS_LIST=""
# CT_LIBC_LOCALES is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_NONE is not set
# CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_AS_HEADERS is not set
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_KERNEL_VERSION_CHOSEN=y
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MIN_KERNEL_VERSION="2.6.9"
CT_LIBC_GLIBC_MIN_KERNEL="2.6.9"

#
# glibc other options
#

#
# WARNING !!!                                            
#

#
#   For glibc >= 2.8, it can happen that the tarballs    
#

#
#   for the addons are not available for download.       
#

#
#   If that happens, bad luck... Try a previous version  
#

#
#   or try again later... :-(                            
#

#
# C compiler
#
CT_CC="gcc"
CT_CC_VERSION="4.8.2"
CT_CC_CORE_PASSES_NEEDED=y
CT_CC_CORE_PASS_1_NEEDED=y
CT_CC_CORE_PASS_2_NEEDED=y
CT_CC_gcc=y
# CT_CC_GCC_SHOW_LINARO is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_9_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_9_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_8_3 is not set
CT_CC_V_4_8_2=y
# CT_CC_V_4_8_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_8_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_7_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_6_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_5_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_7 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_6 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_5 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_4_0 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_6 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_5 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_3 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_2 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_3_1 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_2_4 is not set
# CT_CC_V_4_2_2 is not set
CT_CC_GCC_4_2_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_3_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_4_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_5_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_6_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_7_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_8=y
CT_CC_GCC_4_8_or_later=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_GRAPHITE=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_GRAPHITE=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LTO=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_LTO=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_BUILD_ID=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LNK_HASH_STYLE=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_GMP_MPFR=y
CT_CC_GCC_USE_MPC=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LIBQUADMATH=y
CT_CC_GCC_HAS_LIBSANITIZER=y
# CT_CC_LANG_FORTRAN is not set
CT_CC_SUPPORT_CXX=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_FORTRAN=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_JAVA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_ADA=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJC=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_OBJCXX=y
CT_CC_SUPPORT_GOLANG=y

#
# Additional supported languages:
#
CT_CC_LANG_CXX=y
# CT_CC_LANG_JAVA is not set

#
# gcc other options
#
CT_CC_ENABLE_CXX_FLAGS=""
CT_CC_CORE_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_CC_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
CT_CC_STATIC_LIBSTDCXX=y
# CT_CC_GCC_SYSTEM_ZLIB is not set

#
# Optimisation features
#

#
# Settings for libraries running on target
#
# CT_CC_GCC_ENABLE_TARGET_OPTSPACE is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBMUDFLAP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBGOMP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBSSP is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBQUADMATH is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LIBSANITIZER is not set

#
# Misc. obscure options.
#
CT_CC_CXA_ATEXIT=y
# CT_CC_GCC_DISABLE_PCH is not set
CT_CC_GCC_SJLJ_EXCEPTIONS=m
CT_CC_GCC_LDBL_128=m
# CT_CC_GCC_BUILD_ID is not set
CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_DEFAULT=y
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_SYSV is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_GNU is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE_BOTH is not set
CT_CC_GCC_LNK_HASH_STYLE=""
CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_AUTO=y
# CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_BID is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOAT_DPD is not set
# CT_CC_GCC_DEC_FLOATS_NO is not set

#
# Debug facilities
#
# CT_DEBUG_dmalloc is not set
# CT_DEBUG_duma is not set
CT_DEBUG_gdb=y
CT_GDB_CROSS=y
# CT_GDB_CROSS_STATIC is not set
# CT_GDB_CROSS_SIM is not set
CT_GDB_CROSS_PYTHON=y
CT_GDB_CROSS_EXTRA_CONFIG_ARRAY=""
# CT_GDB_NATIVE is not set
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER=y
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_HAS_IPA_LIB=y
CT_GDB_GDBSERVER_STATIC=y

#
# gdb version
#
# CT_DEBUG_GDB_SHOW_LINARO is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_8 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_7_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_7 is not set
CT_GDB_V_7_6_1=y
# CT_GDB_V_7_5_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_4_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_4 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_3_1 is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_3a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_2a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_1a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_0_1a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_7_0a is not set
# CT_GDB_V_6_8a is not set
CT_GDB_7_2_or_later=y
CT_GDB_7_0_or_later=y
CT_GDB_HAS_PKGVERSION_BUGURL=y
CT_GDB_HAS_PYTHON=y
CT_GDB_INSTALL_GDBINIT=y
CT_GDB_VERSION="7.6.1"
# CT_DEBUG_ltrace is not set
# CT_DEBUG_strace is not set

#
# Companion libraries
#
CT_COMPLIBS_NEEDED=y
CT_GMP_NEEDED=y
CT_MPFR_NEEDED=y
CT_ISL_NEEDED=y
CT_CLOOG_NEEDED=y
CT_MPC_NEEDED=y
CT_COMPLIBS=y
CT_GMP=y
CT_MPFR=y
CT_ISL=y
CT_CLOOG=y
CT_MPC=y
CT_GMP_V_5_1_3=y
# CT_GMP_V_5_1_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_5_0_2 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_5_0_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_2 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_1 is not set
# CT_GMP_V_4_3_0 is not set
CT_GMP_VERSION="5.1.3"
CT_MPFR_V_3_1_2=y
# CT_MPFR_V_3_1_0 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_3_0_0 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_2 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_1 is not set
# CT_MPFR_V_2_4_0 is not set
CT_MPFR_VERSION="3.1.2"
CT_ISL_V_0_12_2=y
# CT_ISL_V_0_11_1 is not set
CT_ISL_VERSION="0.12.2"
CT_CLOOG_V_0_18_1=y
# CT_CLOOG_V_0_18_0 is not set
CT_CLOOG_VERSION="0.18.1"
CT_CLOOG_0_18_or_later=y
CT_MPC_V_1_0_2=y
# CT_MPC_V_1_0_1 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_1_0 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_9 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_8_2 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_8_1 is not set
# CT_MPC_V_0_7 is not set
CT_MPC_VERSION="1.0.2"

#
# Companion libraries common options
#
# CT_COMPLIBS_CHECK is not set

#
# Companion tools
#

#
# READ HELP before you say 'Y' below !!!
#
# CT_COMP_TOOLS is not set
```

I'm not sure, where is the matching options in the toolchain config file?

Comment: You know you can use `ct-ng menuconfig` to change the current configuration right?

Comment: Yes, but can I do this by editing config file? I can't find matching options in the toolchain config file.

Comment: Sure, `.config` is what matters in the end, sorry I wouldn't know how to help you in that case, maybe the authors of ct-ng have a mailing list where it's worth posting.

Answer (score 1):

The output you posted first is the set of flags used to build gcc directly.  Crosstool-ng has an entire build system based on top of that.  There's no directly way to resolve the flags, nor will there necessarily be a one-to-one correlation.  Instead you'll have to either do research on each command-line option to see what it means, and on every crosstool-ng option to see which matches, or you'll need to investigate the crosstool-ng build system to figure out the conditions under which it will set each of those flags.

This is the reason many people copy the crosstool-ng config file into their final toolchain folder.  It makes it easier to replicate the toolchain later.